# Firebase, get specfic chid from parent

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to match branch value in all child of student nodes with the value I already have  and if matched successfully then I want to retrieve 'Student name' value in matched child  see blow image

[image: my database]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for a query in that case.

To match the value of `branch` and then print the value of `studentName` for all matching child nodes, you'd do:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(".../students");
Query query = ref.orderByChild("branch").equalTo("Electronics Engineering");
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot studentSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Log.d(TAG, studentSnapshot.child("studentName").getValue(String.class));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
}
```